# ¿Como tomar una variable y declararla en cada funcion con php?

Tags: php, mysql, poo, codeigniter-3

Tengo una variable definida `$sql` el cual tiene como valor una sentencia `sql` el problema es que necesito la misma sentencia en funciones diferentes, pero no quiero en cada función tener que poner `$sql = "SELECT * FROM....."` sino directamente acceder a ella...

**CODIGO (He recortado la sentencia ya que es demasiado extensa)**

```
public function CountEmpleadosRendimientoBajo_Sede_Competencia($id_empleado)
{
    switch ($area_empleado)
    {
        case '1':
            $where = 'tabla.resultado_lider <= 60';             
        break;

        case '2':
            $where = 'tabla.resultado_lider <= 25';             
        break;                 
    }       

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(tabla.emple_cedula) AS rendimientobajo 
    FROM(
            SELECT 
              public.emple_empleados.emple_id
            FROM
              public.emple_empleados
                INNER JOIN public.udn_unidadnegocio ON (public.emple_empleados.emple_udn_id = public.udn_unidadnegocio.udn_id)
                INNER JOIN public.detalle_evaluacion ON (public.emple_empleados.emple_id = public.detalle_evaluacion.deteva_emple_id)
                INNER JOIN public.detalle_perfil_empleado ON (public.emple_empleados.emple_id = public.detalle_perfil_empleado.detalle_per_emple_id)
                INNER JOIN public.evaluacion ON (public.detalle_evaluacion.deteva_id = public.evaluacion.eva_deteva_id)
                INNER JOIN public.pre_preguntas ON (public.evaluacion.eva_pregunta_id = public.pre_preguntas.pregunta_id)
                INNER JOIN public.detalle_competencia_area ON (public.pre_preguntas.pre_compe_id = public.detalle_competencia_area.detarea_compe_id)
                    AND (public.detalle_perfil_empleado.detalle_per_id_area_empleado = public.detalle_competencia_area.detarea_id_area_empleado)
                INNER JOIN public.compe_competencia ON (public.detalle_competencia_area.detarea_compe_id = public.compe_competencia.compe_id)
                    AND (public.pre_preguntas.pre_compe_id = public.compe_competencia.compe_id)
                INNER JOIN public.per_periodo ON (public.detalle_evaluacion.deteva_per_id = public.per_periodo.per_id)
            WHERE
                public.emple_empleados.emple_id = '$id_empleado'              
             DESC
        ) tabla
            WHERE
              $where";  

    $stmt = $this->db->conn_id->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $resultado = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    return $resultado;
}

public function CountEmpleadosRendimientoMedio_Sede_Competencia($id_empleado)
{
    switch ($area_empleado)
    {
        case '1':
            $where = 'tabla.resultado_lider >= 61 AND tabla.resultado_lider <= 89';             
        break;

        case '2':
            $where = 'tabla.resultado_lider >= 25 AND tabla.resultado_lider <= 45';             
        break;                 
    }       

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(tabla.emple_cedula) AS rendimientobajo 
    FROM(
            SELECT 
              public.emple_empleados.emple_id
            FROM
              public.emple_empleados
                INNER JOIN public.udn_unidadnegocio ON (public.emple_empleados.emple_udn_id = public.udn_unidadnegocio.udn_id)
                INNER JOIN public.detalle_evaluacion ON (public.emple_empleados.emple_id = public.detalle_evaluacion.deteva_emple_id)
                INNER JOIN public.detalle_perfil_empleado ON (public.emple_empleados.emple_id = public.detalle_perfil_empleado.detalle_per_emple_id)
                INNER JOIN public.evaluacion ON (public.detalle_evaluacion.deteva_id = public.evaluacion.eva_deteva_id)
                INNER JOIN public.pre_preguntas ON (public.evaluacion.eva_pregunta_id = public.pre_preguntas.pregunta_id)
                INNER JOIN public.detalle_competencia_area ON (public.pre_preguntas.pre_compe_id = public.detalle_competencia_area.detarea_compe_id)
                    AND (public.detalle_perfil_empleado.detalle_per_id_area_empleado = public.detalle_competencia_area.detarea_id_area_empleado)
                INNER JOIN public.compe_competencia ON (public.detalle_competencia_area.detarea_compe_id = public.compe_competencia.compe_id)
                    AND (public.pre_preguntas.pre_compe_id = public.compe_competencia.compe_id)
                INNER JOIN public.per_periodo ON (public.detalle_evaluacion.deteva_per_id = public.per_periodo.per_id)
            WHERE
                public.emple_empleados.emple_id = '$id_empleado'              
             DESC
        ) tabla
            WHERE
              $where";  

    $stmt = $this->db->conn_id->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $resultado = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    return $resultado;
}
```

Comment: Guardalo en `$sentencia`, por ejemplo, al inicio de la función. Si la misma no cambia, como es lo que parece luego tan sólo tienes que igualar `$sql` a `$sentencia`. `$sql = $sentencia`. O directamente puedes guardar `$sql` al inicio de la función.

Comment: Hola @David gracias por el interes podrias hacerte explicar mejor?

Comment: Vale, acabo de ver detenidamente el código y veo que son funciones diferentes :)

Comment: Si, exacto, ya que no seria logico poner funciones con el mismo nombre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Y si la sacas a una función privada?
Podrias pasarle como argumento el  `where` definido anteriormente

```
 private function getConsulta($where){
        $sql = "SElECT ... WHERE $where";
        return $sql;
    }
```

Y realizas la llamada en cada funcion:

```
$sql = $this->getConsulta($where);
```

Comment: Hola @Carlos Gª-muñoz , gracias por el interes, en la consola me aparece un error y es el sgte como la sentencia (sql) esta trabajando con variables internas en el "where" me dice que estan indefinidas, como podria definirlas?? Gracias

Comment: Te edito la funcion para que le pases el  parametro del ` where `

Answer (score 3):

Si la sentencia sql no varía te propongo la siguiente solución.

Crear en tus funciones [php](/questions/tagged/php) otro parámetro que reciba la sentencia `sql`...

```
public function CountEmpleadosRendimientoMedio_Sede_Competencia($id_empleado, $sql)
    {

// resto código...

}
```

Al inicio de las funciones en tu página PHP declaras una variable que contenga dicha instrucción $sql, por ejemplo:

```
$sentencia = "SELECT COUNT(tabla.emple_cedula) AS rendimientobajo 
    FROM(
            SELECT 
              public.emple_empleados.emple_id
            FROM
              public.emple_empleados
                INNER JOIN public.udn_unidadnegocio ON (public.emple_empleados.emple_udn_id = public.udn_unidadnegocio.udn_id)
                INNER JOIN public.detalle_evaluacion ON (public.emple_empleados.emple_id = public.detalle_evaluacion.deteva_emple_id)
                INNER JOIN public.detalle_perfil_empleado ON (public.emple_empleados.emple_id = public.detalle_perfil_empleado.detalle_per_emple_id)
                INNER JOIN public.evaluacion ON (public.detalle_evaluacion.deteva_id = public.evaluacion.eva_deteva_id)
                INNER JOIN public.pre_preguntas ON (public.evaluacion.eva_pregunta_id = public.pre_preguntas.pregunta_id)
                INNER JOIN public.detalle_competencia_area ON (public.pre_preguntas.pre_compe_id = public.detalle_competencia_area.detarea_compe_id)
                    AND (public.detalle_perfil_empleado.detalle_per_id_area_empleado = public.detalle_competencia_area.detarea_id_area_empleado)
                INNER JOIN public.compe_competencia ON (public.detalle_competencia_area.detarea_compe_id = public.compe_competencia.compe_id)
                    AND (public.pre_preguntas.pre_compe_id = public.compe_competencia.compe_id)
                INNER JOIN public.per_periodo ON (public.detalle_evaluacion.deteva_per_id = public.per_periodo.per_id)
            WHERE
                public.emple_empleados.emple_id = '$id_empleado'              
             DESC
        ) tabla
            WHERE
              $where";
```

Luego en tus funciones PHP tendrías que hacer referencia al segundo parámetro de dicha sentencia sql.

Por ejemplo quedaría así para la función `CountEmpleadosRendimientoBajo_Sede_Competencia`:

```
public function CountEmpleadosRendimientoBajo_Sede_Competencia($id_empleado, $sql)
{
    switch ($area_empleado)
    {
        case '1':
            $where = 'tabla.resultado_lider <= 60';             
        break;

        case '2':
            $where = 'tabla.resultado_lider <= 25';             
        break;                 
    }

    $stmt = $this->db->conn_id->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $resultado = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    return $resultado;
}
```

Y así para la otra función `CountEmpleadosRendimientoMedio_Sede_Competencia`

```
public function CountEmpleadosRendimientoMedio_Sede_Competencia($id_empleado, $sql)
{
    switch ($area_empleado)
    {
        case '1':
            $where = 'tabla.resultado_lider >= 61 AND tabla.resultado_lider <= 89';             
        break;

        case '2':
            $where = 'tabla.resultado_lider >= 25 AND tabla.resultado_lider <= 45';             
        break;                 
    }

    $stmt = $this->db->conn_id->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $resultado = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    return $resultado;
}
```

**EJEMPLO**

```
$sentencia = "SELECT ...";
CountEmpleadosRendimientoMedio_Sede_Competencia("el_valor_que_sea", $sentencia);
```

Comment: Entonces la sentencia que se encuentra en la variable $sql la declaro por fuera de las funciones?

Comment: Sí, te lo añado con un ejemplo, voy.

Comment: Si, te agradezco, ya que no me quedo muy claro declarar $sql dentro de la funcion y luego declara la variable $sentencia.

Comment: Una cosa es como nombres el parámetro de una función y otra es lo que contenga dicho parámetro, que puede ser una cadena, entero, etc. o el nombre de la variable que hayas declarado y asignado previamente y que esta a su vez contenga una cadena, entero, booleano, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Que quede claro: **es una mala práctica** hacer lo siguiente:

Puedes usar una variable *global*; la declaras fuera de tus funciones, y accedes a ella así:

```
$sql = "...";

function lalala( ) {
  global $sql;

  ...
}
```

También podrías **definirla** en algún archivo común que uses en todos los demás; esta solución es **mejor** que la anterior; los defines son **de solo lectura**: **no se pueden modificar**.

```
define( 'SENTENCIA_SQL', "..." );
...

function lalala( ) {
  SENTENCIA_SQL ... // SIN las comillas.
```

Comment: Hola @Trauma intente hacer lo que dices, pero el problema es que php marca un error por tener esa variable por fuera de una funcion

Comment: Pues no se, a mi me van: `<?php $a=10;` no me marca ningún error ni problema. Mira la [documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: lo intentaste dentro de una clase?